# Problems that need to be refreshed when using history.push() in react router

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I want to move the page when login success on redux now. The way I found out is to use `createBrowserHistory()`. So I implemented it. The page was then moved from redux using a temporary `history.push ("/Dashboard");`. It changes the `url` of the browser, but it does not move unless the user refreshes it. I used `createBrowserHistory ({forceRefresh: true})` to solve this problem. But this will refresh the page. (The screen will blink.) I can't change the settings of the webpack because I used the CRA. What do I do when I try to solve this problem?

**history.js**

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

// export default createBrowserHistory({ forceRefresh: true });
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

**index.js**

```
/* import other modules... */
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import history from "./utils/history";

const logger = createLogger();
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware({
  context: { history: history },
}); 

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(
      sagaMiddleware, 
      logger
    )
  )
);
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga); 
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**redux**

```
/* import other modules... */
import history from "../utils/history";

/* code ... */
// redux-saga
export function* login(user) {
  try {
    const res = yield call(apiClient, {
      url: "/login",
      method: "post",
      data: user,
      timeout: 4000,
    });
    console.log(res);
  
    history.push("/Dashboard");
    yield put({
      type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      user: user, 
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    yield put({
      type: LOGIN_ERROR,
      error: true,
    });
  }
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <AuthRoute path="/Dashboard/:id" component={Dashboard} />
        <AuthRoute exact={true} path="/Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="/" component={LoginPage} />
        <Route path="/Loginpage" component={LoginPage} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
function Dashboard(props) {
  let location = useLocation();
  console.log(location.pathname);
  const tableRender = () => {
    switch (location.pathname) {
      case "/case1": // pathname
        return <CommonTable />;
      case "/case2":
        return <CommonTable2 />;
    }
  };
  // const user = useSelector((state) => state.loginReducer.user, []);

  return (
    <>
      <GlobalHead />
      <Layout>
        <GlobalSide />
        <LocalSide />
        <Layout className="site-layout">
          <Content style={{ margin: "0 16px" }}>
            <SubHeader />
            <div className="Content-area">{tableRender()}</div>
          </Content>
          <GlobalFooter />
        </Layout>
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: How are you rendering your routes? Are you by any chance using more than one routing context? Can you show us how you render your app in a `Router`?

Comment: I added the router rendering to the body.

Comment: Have you tried useHistory() provided by react-router-dom?

Comment: This is a js file, not a jsx file, because the part that moves the page takes place in the redux. That's I can't use useHistory().

Comment: Do you mind posting also your `Dashboard` component? You've some peculiarity with your route definitions, I just want to trace from root to component you are attempting to navigate to.

Comment: added the `Dashboard` to the body.

Comment: @cozy60 is there any specific reason you want to handle it in your redux file. It is much easier to handle it in your component after you call login function

Comment: I connected login success action dispatch in form onSubmit().The dashboard is a page that blocks unauthorized users.So, if press the login button first, it will be blocked because it is an unauthorized user. I can access the page by clicking login again after being blocked, but I thought it was a bad way, so I didn't run it in the component file. `dispatch(loginRequest(user));
      history.push("/Dashboard");`

Comment: Ok, I suspect it maybe because your store provider wraps your `Router` so the `history` has no routing context above it in the React tree. I just wanted to rule out multiple routing contexts.  What happens if you invert these and have the `Router` wrap your store provider?

Comment: How can I do invert these and have the Router Wrap store provider? I looked up an example of it but I didn't understand what the story was about. Can I change the location of `Provider store={store}` and `Router history={history}` in the `index.js` file? I'm so sorry I didn't understand.

Comment: Ok, was worth a shot. Could you try creating a *running* codesandbox minimal example that reproduces this issue we could live debug in?

Comment: I made a demo! https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-darkness-umijz?file=/src/index.js. I don't know if this will be okay. If you get an error message, please pull out the browser in code sanbox and run it. Thanks!

Comment: Ran your sandbox, found the issue, updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loading your codesandbox and running it there's a warning in the console which makes immediately clear what the issue is.

> Warning: `<BrowserRouter>` ignores the history prop. To use a custom
> history, use `import { Router }` instead of `import { BrowserRouter as Router }`.

The solution is to simply use `Router` instead of `BrowserRouter` in `index.js`.

```
import { Router } from "react-router-dom"; // <-- import Router
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import rootReducer, { rootSaga } from "./modules/index";
import history from "./utils/history";

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware({
  context: { history: history }
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

[image: Edit problems-that-need-to-be-refreshed-when-using-history-push-in-react-router]

Comment: Thank you! But it's still not working. I still don't know the problem.

Comment: @cozy60 No worries. Added comment above.

Comment: Thank you VERY much for your kindness. Thank you very much for solving the problem. Your help saved my code. Thank you so much again!